# "Path is not legal" error when loading data from S3 into external Hive table located in S3 in EMR

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive, emr

I have an EMR cluster that I'm running Hive on. I have an external table on S3 defined as such:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `blah`(                                   |
|   `blah1` string,                                               |
|   `blah2` string)                                               |
| PARTITIONED BY (                                                |
|   `blah3` string,                                               |
|   `blah4` string,                                               |
| ROW FORMAT DELIMITED                                            |
|   FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'                                     |
| STORED AS INPUTFORMAT                                           |
|   'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'                    |
| OUTPUTFORMAT                                                    |
|   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'  |
| LOCATION                                                        |
|   's3://REDACTED/events'                                        |
| TBLPROPERTIES (                                                 |
|   'transient_lastDdlTime'='REDACTED')                           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This table has some data that I'm able to see via `SELECT` statements in beeline. That data came from a transfer using s3distcp.

The issue that I'm running into is that I get the following error when I try to load data via a `LOAD DATA INPATH` command:

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10028]: Line 1:17 Path is not legal ''s3://REDACTED/FILE_I_WANT_TO_LOAD'': Move from: s3://REDACTED/FILE_I_WANT_TO_LOAD to: s3://REDACTED/PARTITION_IN_TABLE is not valid. Please check that values for params "default.fs.name" and "hive.metastore.warehouse.dir" do not conflict. (state=42000,code=10028)
```

Note that the file I'm trying to load and the table I'm trying to load into exist in different buckets.

I think this issue comes down to setting S3 as the base file system for Hive but I've tried editing `default.fs.name` and `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` to both be the S3 bucket containing the table. Doing that produced the same exact error.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use LOAD, just define an external table  for each S3 location and then use a INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... style query.

Comment: Yep. Apparently LOAD just flat-out doesn't work with S3.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with location as **s3n://**